# Ошибка при подаче аргумента в контруктор компонента

Tags: angular, jwt

Использую npm пакет angular2-jwt. Именно при добавлении JwtHelper в конструктор, html компонента не отображается и в браузере возникает ошибка.

компонент:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class HomeComponent {

constructor (private router: Router, private jwtHelper: JwtHelper) { }

}
```

ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Помогите

Компонент:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class HomeComponent {
  private jwtHelper: JwtHelper;
constructor (private router: Router) { }

logOut() {
  localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
}

isUserAuthenticated() {
  let token: string = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  if (token != null) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: вы `AuthModule` импортировали?

Comment: @overthesanity, в каком файле он должен быть импортирован? я написал проблемный объект, как свойство вне конструктора, вроде пока работает.

Comment: в смысле в каком файле? вы доку `angular2-jwt` читали?

Comment: @overthesanity, сейчас только открыл, я пишу по туториалу, там все немного по другому, возможно я где-то что то не дописал.

Comment: @overthesanity, я дописал. Все отлично работает, добавлять объект в конструктор не обязательно.

Comment: вы добавили модуль и все заработало?

Comment: @overthesanity, нет, просто выписал private jwtHelper: JwtHelper; вне конструктора, как свойство. Мне кажется проблема не в правильности использования библиотеки JWT, просто, по-моему, в ангуларе кривой конструктор компонента. Это уже не первый раз такая проблема именно с ним, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868691.

Comment: в вашем примере я не вижу чтобы свойство было вне вонструктора

Comment: @overthesanity, добавил код компонента, взгляните

Comment: вам нужно понять как работает DI в angular и typescript, для этого советую вам эту статью https://medium.com/@overthesanity/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-typescript-%D0%B8-angular-ecbbd8e9b938

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо, буду заучивать понемногу